# How to Process my PubSub Message Object and Write all objects into BigQuery in Apache Beam using python?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to write all the elements of a Pub/Sub message (data,attributes,messageId and publish_time) to BigQuery using Apache Beam and wanted the data to be as:

| data | attr | key | publishTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data | attr | key | publishTime |

I am currently using the following piece of code to transform the message and wanted to save it in the table shown above:

```
( demo  
      | "Decoding Pub/Sub Message" + input_subscription >> beam.Map(lambda r : data_decoder.decode_base64(r))
      | "Parsing Pub/Sub Message" + input_subscription >> beam.Map(lambda r : data_parser.parseJsonMessage(r))
      | "Write to BigQuery Table"  + input_subscription  >> io.WriteToBigQuery('{0}:{1}'.format(project_name, dest_table_id),
                                                                        schema=schema, write_disposition=io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND, create_disposition = io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED ))
```

I wanted to store data in encoded way, column named as data and value as (element.data) and the values for rest of the columns.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope it can help.

I give an example based on your use case, I mocked a `PubSubMessage` with `Beam` in an unit test :

```py
def test_beam_pubsub_to_bq(self):
        with TestPipeline() as p:
            message = PubsubMessage(
                data=b'{"test" : "value"}',
                attributes={'label': 'label'},
                message_id='message33444',
                publish_time=datetime.datetime.now()
            )

            result = (p
                      | beam.Create([message])
                      | 'Map' >> beam.Map(self.to_bq_element))
            result | "Print outputs" >> beam.Map(log_element)

    def to_bq_element(self, message: PubsubMessage):
        return {
            'data': message.data,
            'attr': json.dumps(message.attributes),
            'key': message.message_id,
            'publishTime': message.publish_time.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        }
```

- I read a `PubSubMessage`
- Map the `PubSubMessage` to a `Dict` in order to write the element to `Bigquery`

I have the following result :

```
{
   'data': b'{"test" : "value"}', 
   'attr': '{"label": "label"}', 
   'key': 'message33444', 
   'publishTime': '2022-10-07 09:37:33'
}
```

- For `data` I used a `Python` `bytes`, I think the good related type in `Bigquery` is `BYTES` : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types
- For `att`, I used a Json `String`, I initially had a `Dict`
- `key` is a `String`
- `publishTime` is a `String` with timestamp as `ISO` format

Don't hesitate to adapt this example to fit perfectly on your need.

The result `Dict` element for `Bigquery` in the `Beam` transformation must match exactly the schema of the `Bigquery` table.

The example with the `BigqueryIO` `write` :

```py
def test_beam_pubsub_to_bq(self):
        with TestPipeline() as p:
            message = PubsubMessage(
                data=b'{"test" : "value"}',
                attributes={'label': 'label'},
                message_id='message33444',
                publish_time=datetime.datetime.now()
            )

            (p
               | beam.Create([message])
               | 'Map' >> beam.Map(self.to_bq_element)
               | "Print outputs" >> beam.Map(log_element)
               | "Write to BigQuery Table"  + input_subscription  >> io.WriteToBigQuery('{0}:{1}'.format(project_name, dest_table_id),
                                                                        schema=schema, write_disposition=io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND, create_disposition = io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED ))

    def to_bq_element(self, message: PubsubMessage):
        return {
            'data': message.data,
            'attr': json.dumps(message.attributes),
            'key': message.message_id,
            'publishTime': message.publish_time.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        }
```

Comment: This clears out things for me, thanks again mate!